# Create a subclass of a class using parent's init - from another class

Tags: objective-c, initialization

**Edit: This downvoting syndrom here sucks big time. I asked a question where I in my opinion showed that I did my homework, and asked for advice. The upvoted answers implied going with compile time warnings, whereas my own and probably most clean OOP way didn't receive any interest.**

Brief overview in order to understand why I need this and what I try to do: I'm writing an ORM that implements the data mapper pattern. A mapper (i.e. for SQLite results) must create subclasses of an entity class - using the initializer of the base entity class. So there is the problem.

The mapper does not, and should not, know about specific classes. Mapping descriptions and specific mappers for different data sources are abstracted away from the entity class, and by design part of the entity description.

Entities are similar to NSManagedObject, though the ORM follows a different pattern. The description any entity is created with is similar to NSEntityDescription (but also following a different pattern and purpose).

So my goal is to create entities that I know are subclasses of ManagedEntity, using the init method of ManagedEntity.

So the init of my mapper looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithEntityClass:(Class)EntityClass entityDescriptor:(EntityDescription*)entityDescriptor
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    _EntityClass = EntityClass; 
    _entityDescription = entityDescription;

    ... (assert that class is of subclass of ManagedEntity)
}
```

And some time later in my mapper I then want to create the concrete entity:

```
-(void)createEntityWithSQLiteResultSet:(sqlite3_stmt*)resultSet
{
    // Problem: How to init a class known to be a subclass of ManagedEntity?  
    ManagedEntity *newEntity = [[_EntityClass] alloc]     initWithEntityDescription:_entityDescription];
}
```

So how do I create this child class of ManagedEntity, using the init of ManagedEntity?

Sure, I could use respondsToSelector() for initWithEntityDescription and invoke that. But something tells me there should be a more elegant way where the class kind is already known. Also, respondsToSelector and selector invocation will do a runtime check only. Even though the entity initializer should not change, it seems a bad choice to lose compile time checking if this method exists.

Comment: Why not declare initWithEntityDescription as a method in ManagedEntity, and override it in each specific subclass?

Comment: initWithEntityDescription already is a method in ManagedEntity - that is what I want to call. Whether or not a subclass overrides this doesn't matter (would be ok to do) - the problem is that EntityClass is of type Class - and it must be. In the mapper I don't know of any concrete entity classes / models, I just know and assert for that they are a subclass of ManagedEntity.

Comment: I probably don't understand the problem correctly yet. But `ManagedEntity *newEntity = [[_EntityClass alloc]     initWithEntityDescription:_entityDescription];` should just work and create an object of the  `_EntityClass` subclass. (Note that there is a syntax error in your code.)

Comment: _EntityClass is a class of just type Class - it doesn't know this init method. It's known to be a subclass of it, but nevertheless must be initialized using the concrete class passed as argument. i.e. it could be a class "ExhibitorEntity" which inherits from ManagedEnitity.

Comment: ... So calling the initWithDescriptors on the ExhibitorEntity class should create a ExhibitorEntity instance. But the class ExhibitorEntity is unknown to the mapper (and should be by design).

Answer (score 5):

As part of your mapping, you must know what subclass you need. Then use

```
ManagedEntity *newEntity = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] initWithEntityDescription:_entityDescription];
```

EDIT:
I was building out this in a GitHub project as I promised and realized why it may not compile. You must have `-initWithEntityDescription:` declared in a known class that is accessible within the scope. In this case, it would mean that you must declare and implement `ManagedEntity -initWithEntityDescription:` and have have `#import "ManagedEntity.h" at the top of your file.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense. The method initWithEntityDescription will be unknown in your example.

Comment: no it won't. As he said "you must know what subclass you need" -- it makes sense to me

Comment: This just won't work. Period. [NSClassFromString(className) alloc] doesn't know initWithEntityDescription. It won't even compile this way. So people giving this an upvote don't know.

Comment: It will compile and run just fine. Try it before you make wild claims.

Comment: I would give you a downvote if I could... Ok, that is what the compiler says: "No known instance method for selector 'initWithEntityDescription'".

Comment: Many people do not understand that Objective C is NOT a strongly typed language, in the traditional sense. The static analyzer enforces strong typing. The compiler does not.

Comment: I won't argue with you. I will post a GitHub project when I get home in a bit.

Comment: @benjist :: sorry but I don't think you should make such absolute statements. + be nicer + learn your stuff -- the fact YOU dont get something to work doesnt make it wrong.

Comment: What you suggested does neither compile with default settings, nor would it behave in the way I need it. I could turn off default warnings in the project to have the initWithEntityDescription compile - and yes it would work. But what you suggested still is not good and will have a warning.

Comment: Guys, I know Objective-C. And I'm going to post an answer that doesn't produce warnings about unknown methods.

Comment: read Neals last comment. it is a DYNAMIC language. the methods are checked at runtime

Comment: Gosh I'll whip an example. gimme a sec

Comment: Performance is an issue here' I'll go write my correct answer

Comment: Guys, be fair and upvote my question again. I gave a correct and possibly better answer.

Comment: @benjist Your question is good and I gave you an up vote for it. I disagree with your solution though.

Comment: From your edit it seems you actually implemented a protocol, which you disagreed with in my solution.

Comment: For someone who claims to "know Objective-C," the difference between a class hierarchy and a protocol should be more obvious. Additionally, your initial example already had a base `ManagedEntity` class, so my initial answer should have not needed any clarification.

Comment: For someone downvoting correct solutions, you show some unwillingness to understand: A class can be well declared as conforming to a protocoll, as can a instance be. Class <Proto> is as valid as id <Proto>. Interpreting an instance e.g. ExhibitorEntity, which is derived from ManagedEntity, as a ManagedEntity is as valid as interpreting an NSMutableDictionary as NSDictionary. No? Understood?

Comment: @Neal's answer here is good, and the correct way to approach it in ObjC. No additional protocol, ObjC runtime, ivars, or anything else is really warranted. The one thing that was missing in the original version was the required `#import` to avoid the warning (Neal has since added that). What may be confusing to the OP is that `+alloc` returns type `id`, not `instancetype`. As long as the compiler knows that the selector `-initWithEntityDescription:` applies to *any* known class, it will treat it as ok at compile time. Without the `#import`, the compiler doesn't know this selector exists.

Comment: It would be completely appropriate to pass the class itself rather than the name of the class (so replace `NSClassFromString(className)` with a Class variable `entityClass`). This is somewhat similar to how @benjist's answer works, but the extra protocol complexity is unnecessary.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, by default settings this won't even compile using XCode 5. You could add a category on NSObject to make initWithDescriptor known.... But... No! As bbum told, the real deal would be to use a class cluster. But that would mean more overhead compared to using a protocol. Other than that, I want to see how this method should be known without a warning, without using a category on NSObject. Still he didn't post his code. I'll be glad to see it works, but I feel his resistance means he doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

To reinforce Neal's correct answer that the OP claims cant work because he knows objC :)

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface TestMapper : NSObject

- (NSManagedObject*)createClassForEntity:(NSEntityDescription*)entity context:(NSManagedObjectContext*)ctx;

@end
```

---

```
#import "TestMapper.h"

@implementation TestMapper

- (NSDictionary*)entityToClassMap {
    return nil; //TODO ;)
}

- (NSManagedObject*)createClassForEntity:(NSEntityDescription*)entity context:(NSManagedObjectContext*)ctx {
    NSString *className = self.entityToClassMap[entity.name];
    assert(className);

    return [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:ctx];
}

@end
```

---

alternative using the runtime you want

```
id cls = NSClassFromString(className);
id alloced_cls = objc_msgSend(cls, @selector(alloc));
id newEntity = objc_msgSend(alloced_cls, @selector(initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:), entity, ctx);
return newEntity;
```

Comment: DISCLAIMER written inline

Comment: See my answer. Your's will work, but have warnings and is no good OOP way.

Comment: Two points to note here: It should be avoided to call unknown methods. That Obj-C allows this doesn't mean it's clean, and there is a reason why when in new projects a warning about it is handled as error by default. Secondly, I'm not absolute sure about it, but it could also be that sending messages where signature is not known at compile time could also lead to required method signature lookup at runtime. Not sure about that, but if so it's to be avoided in the ORM where I literally need to create several thousands of instances.

Comment: The first part of your post is great and I love that you reenforced my solution. However, I believe the alternative portion that you posted will leak memory under ARC.

Comment: Why should it? All created objects are returned, what the receiver does with the enity / when to release them is up to him. The two args (EntityClass, descriptor) are both nilled on dealloc. I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: It would be nice if you could accept my kind edit about the compile time warning, which is treated as error by default in a new project with XCode 5. Second attempt.