# Init a class with one argument using objc_msgSend

Tags: objective-c

**EDIT: Yes, I did it wrong. It's well possibly knowing the init method by using a protocol on class level. This is something I rarely do, so that didn't come to my mind at first (see linked question about my answer to it using a protocol). So yes, this question is broken. As bbum said, there should be absolutely no reason to do this.**

Background to my question in [1].

For a design reason (data mapper pattern) I need to initialize classes which I know are subclasses of a certain base class (ManagedEntity). I assert for this once - then later I want to create as many instances, and as fast as possible (I'm programming for iOS). However, since the class where I need to create the concrete instances in doesn't know any of the model classes, the meta class stored and used to create entity instances of is just known to be of type Class.

Long story short: I can't simply use [[[_EntityClass] alloc] initWithBlah:something], since EntityClass is unknown, just known as type Class there, hence the init method initWithBlah is unknown of course - but I know it must exist (it must be by design a subclass of the base class, which is asserted once when the mapper is initialized).

So in order to create instances of the unknown class with the init method that I know it exists, I need to construct a method invocation. This should call the initWith:something selector on the unknown class and create an instance of it.

I think I should use objc_msgSend rather than NSInvocation, because the latter is supposed to be an order of magnitude slower [2]. The init method is supposed to not change, and requires one argument.

So... What would be the equivalent to:

```
ManagedEntity *newEntity = [[ManagedEntity] alloc] initWithEntityDescription:_entityDescription];
```

with objc_msgSend?

[1] [Create a subclass of a class using parent's init - from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477173/create-a-subclass-of-a-class-using-parents-init-from-another-class?noredirect=1#comment28886978_19477173)

[2] http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations-leopard-edition.html

Comment: Why the heck do I get downvotes on this? Please show you understood what I try to do, and reason on it...

Comment: I don't get but using objc_msgSend directly to alloc/init classes is wrong. It is against OOP and against encapsulation and worst of all it heavily relies on internals -> you should really look at the problem again.

Comment: [1] seems a dupe though

Comment: The explanation is given in [1]. I did my research, and this is a corner case. A mapper by design doesn't know concrete models. Similar to how NSManagedObject is, a model is a subclass of ManagedEntity that I inside the mapper must create using a param.

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate of my previous question. My previous questin asked about a way to know the method, since I know it's a subclass of a known class. I specifically wanted to AVOID using NSInvocation, or objc_msgSend - as stated in the question. This is NOT possible, and therefore this NEW question, asking for exactly what the previous question was NOT about.

Comment: @benjist If you have a known selector -- if the selector is not determined at runtime -- then **there is absolutely no reason to use `objc_msgSend()`**.  Simply ensure that the compiler has parsed an `@interface` with the method declaration prior to the call site and it all "just works".

Comment: @bbum Thanks, understood. I'll fix the edit of my question to not suggest doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id cls = NSClassFromString(className);
id alloced_cls = objc_msgSend(cls, @selector(alloc));
id newEntity = objc_msgSend(alloced_cls, @selector(initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:), entity, ctx);
return newEntity;
```

Comment: I now figured that I did it wrong, using protocol on a class level default method initialization is well possible. Thanks for your answer, that was what I was asking for

Comment: You *could* do it that way, but there is no point.  Simply call the methods directly, using a cast if you have to.   Note that `cls` should be of type `Class`, not `id`.

Comment: I know and said so N times :) but this what he EXPLICITLY wanted

Answer (score 2):

Better:

```
Class klass = NSClassFromString(className);
id newEntity = [[klass alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:ctx];
```

There is no reason to use `objc_msgSend()` directly when you have a fixed selector.  You can always call the selector directly using the normal syntax.   Worst case, you might have to type-cast the return value of one of the calls.

The only requirement is that the compiler has seen the declaration of `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` sometime prior to compiling the above call site.

Example:

```
@interface NSObject(BobsYourUncle)
- (void)bob:sender;
@end

...

    Class klass = NSClassFromString(@"NSManagedObject");
    [[klass alloc] bob:nil];
```

The above compiles just fine.  Not that I'd recommend hanging random definitions off of `NSObject`.   Instead, `#import` the abstract superclass's declaration (which should contain the selector declaration).

Comment: By default in new XCode 5 (iOS, others probably also) projects unknown methods are treated as errors (in my opinion for good reason). So it won't compile, unless settings are changed. Admittedly, as I said I did it wrong - I now simply store a "Class <ManagedEntityProtocol>" iVar in the mapper, and that protocol knows the initWith:

Comment: @benjist  But this isn't an unknown method;  as long as you `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` prior to that call site, then it compiles fine with all of the `selector` related warnings enabled.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. But as you said that category on NSObject isn't nice ;). I feel quite comfortable using the protocol (which declares iniWith..). Do you see a reason not doing it this way?. Btw, I think this answer should be left as broken. Maybe we can continue in my previous question. Actaully this one was indeed about objc_message_send which admittedly is just wrong.

Comment: @benjist Do like a class cluster; create an abstract superclass that implements the method(s) that are always implemented in subclasses (the abstract may even `@throw` if any of them are invoked, forcing implementation down).   Use a class to declare that the return from `+alloc` is of type `(AbstractClass*)` and call the method directly.   This eliminates the need to repeat the protocol declaration and you now have a single place (the abstract super) to implement common logic, which is generally inevitably needed.

Comment: well he WANTED obi_msgSend I know this is cooler

Comment: @Daij-Djan He actually provided code that would compile without warning, which somebody else after previous claim later found out actually didn't compile in a new project. After all discussion it may still seem irrelevant to you, but it is not to me and others - you cannot always change settings in a corporate project, which now are treated as errors in new projects (by good reason). By all our discussion, you still missed the point and even declined my edit to your code example (which was to temporarily allow unknown methodsusing pragma statement).

Comment: I didn't decline it. 4 others did. I really didn't ;) I would have - but I didnt + did you try the code -- it wasn't my answer at first :) there is no warning. you missed the include or did something but my code there was (as written) error and warning free in any project.

Comment: also bbum confirmed it . 2nd comment here

Comment: this is the fifth or so person  to tell you the same thing ;)